# Change date 2013-08-09 => 09-Aug-2013

Tags: php, date

I want to change format of date by 2013-08-09 to 09-Aug-2013, I tried this:

```
echo $date=date("Y-m-d");
//output 2013-08-09
echo date("d-M-Y",mktime(0-0-0,$date));
```

but this code showing `10-Aug-2013`
I dont know why this showing date 10 instead of 09.

Answer would be highly appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: Why do not simply look into manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ??

Comment: your `mktime()` call is completely and utterly wrong. I suspect you intended to use `strtottime()` instead, but the way you're doing it would be badly wrong even for that. I suggest reading some basic examples from the manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

following is easier:

```
echo date("d-M-Y",strtotime($date));
```

at mktime you have to subtract one day

Comment: Thanks Patrick, why was it showing next from current date.

Comment: look here for the answer [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) can't tell you in short sry

Comment: Thanks its realy awesome, but i dont knw y my question being downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing in the parameters to [`mktime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) properly. `mktime` requires 6 integer parameters where as you have 1 integer and 1 string here.

Try using a [`DateTime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object instead:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('d-M-Y');
```

Comment: +1 for very good explanation...Thanks for knowledge... :)